# How to filter PySpark SQL dataframe read from Elasticsearch by metadata field (by _id for example)?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-spark

I am reading PySpark SQL Dataframe from Elasticsearch index, with the read option of `es.read.metadata=True`. I want to filter the data by condition on metadata field, but get an empty result, although there should be result. Is it possible to get the actual result?

I did get result when I used `limit` on the dataframe, even with a very big number, even larger then the dataframe size.

In addition, I did get result when using other not `_metadata` related field.

for example:

```py
df.where(df._metadata._score > 1.0).select(df._metadata._id).show()
```

the result is empty:

```
+--------------+
|_metadata[_id]|
+--------------+
+--------------+
```

But when using `limit`:

```py
df.limit(1000000).where(df._metadata._score > 1.0).select(df._metadata._id).show()
```

the result is not empty:

```
+--------------------+
|      _metadata[_id]|
+--------------------+
|cICqm2gBHl8Vy6RZyu_L|
+--------------------+
```